# Location-Aware Features: Engaging Users with Relevant Content and Offers

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create an app to find the exact location of IP address. I did some research on IP addresses and many more. But whenever I try to locate an IP address it provides the location of Internet Service Provider. I want to track the exact geolocation or long & lat of that place. So can anyone help me out to let me know how to find the geolocation of Dynamic IP address. what plugin in can use Location of the user to improve user Interaction

Answer (score 0):

It would be a huge security risk if you could do that with ease.

To not violatate your user's privacy, you have to ask them for permission:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API/Using_the_Permissions_API